# Why isn't UIAlertView Showing?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios-simulator

For some reason screen gets dark and freezes, alert is not shown... can someone please help?

Thanks in advance!

```
} else {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Hello!" 
                                                message:@"Hello!" delegate:self 
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"Done" 
                                      otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}
```

Comment: Have you checked that you're getting to that else statement? Add a NSLog above the alloc/init of the alertview to make sure.

Comment: Yes, i'm 100% sure, i've placed a breakpoint there and it stops there...

Answer (score 15):

You are probably calling `show` from a background thread, call it on the main thread like this:

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Hello!" 
                                            message:@"Hello!" delegate:self 
                                            cancelButtonTitle:@"Done" 
                                            otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(show)
                            withObject:nil
                            waitUntilDone:NO];
[alert release];
```

Answer (score 0):

Delegate is correct, but maybe because your do a release at the end it may cause a problem.

Try with a nil delegate :-)

For example :

```
UIAlertView *alertView;
alertView = [ [ UIAlertView alloc ] init ];
[ alertView setMessage:@"Hello World" ];
[ alertView show ];
[ alertView release ];
```

If it works, then it was the delegate and you need to declare the variable as a class var. Or it maybe be elsewhere.

Comment: Doesn't work, it seems that it loops and calls the IBAction again (this else block is inside an action called by a button). With your code, application exists with a Program received signal:  “SIGKILL”.

Comment: My code is correct. As said by others persons, your problem is not here ^^ Maybe could you give us all the content of your function?

Comment: It seems the problem isn't in this function. Mmmm what event did you associate to this callback function? Can you try NSLog(@"Test"); something to check if the function is really called several times ? Or maybe set a boolean to verify if login is already in process.

Comment: The event is Touch Up Inside (UIButton *btnLogin)... should i pick another event for the button "click"?

Comment: No the event is the good one. So did you try to print in the terminal a log (to see if it appears several times, or not ^^).

Comment: Apparently there is no loop.... 2011-03-16 22:28:46.671 cgd[9161:207] start
2011-03-16 22:28:46.980 cgd[9161:207] else

Comment: Maybe it's because of your asi request ? did you try deleting all the request and just doing an UIAlertView ? [sorry, time to sleep here. I will respond tomorrow... in 10h ^^]

Comment: You are right, i removed everything except the UIAlertView and it works... hmmmm...

Comment: Found the problem.... i think i had releases where i wasn't supposed to :( thanks for your help and time!

Answer (score 0):

Is this alert maybe sitting in a big loop and you are not running on multiple threads? The screen darkening and nothing happening is something I equate with running a long process on the main thread (so the UI doesn't refresh and show the alert).

Comment: Yes, exactly... it seems that it loops and calls the IBAction again. I just don't know how to avoid it (it's my first iPhone project).

Answer (score 0):

You get a dark screen without a popup, or slower popup if you show the UIAlertView from a background thread. Just out it back in the main thread and it will be fine. I just had this problem last week.